# Most current edit on Mobile<->Web App Two Way Syncronization

Tags: web-applications, synchronization, mobile-application

The title basically says it. I have an application which is usable as a web app anda mobile app. The mobile app receives and sends data to the server. There are several cases to cover when doing a sync but I need to somehow know which is the most current edit. I plan to sync at start and stop of the mobile app. The most difficult case is probably when the user starts the app without internet and closes it still not having internet. How to solve this?

Please note that timestamps are useless since you are on a mobile device where the clock might be changed by the user.

What would you suggest? I don't want to ask the user about conflict solving but implement some automation. (Just take the most current one)

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

timestamp isn't useless, you just need to rethink how you use it. In this case the servers time is god. when the mobile device establishes contacts the server, the mobile can let the server know how long ago from now the data in question was created. Then once the information is transferred the server knows to set the time for that data as the current time on the server minus the amount of time that provided by the mobile.

So for example:

- 8am your data updated directly on webapp - correct time
- 9am data updated on mobile - (no network access + time not trusted)
- 10am more data updated to webapp (currently 2 data entries on server)
- 11am your mobile gets network access and contacts the server. Your mobile knows that the 9am data was 2 hours ago, so this is what it needs to tell the server. The server receives the data and now knows that it's 2 hours old. The server is able to persist the new information with the time stamp of: (current time on server -
  2hours).

This way the time for the 9am data will be correct regardless of the time on the mobile device.

Comment: I  thought about that, but how will you get the time? The user might c hange it. Anyway, atm I'm doing some usecases using this method. I also think it is the best thing to do.

Comment: it doesn't matter what time is set on the mobile device as long as it's not getting changed between creation and upload. It'd only require the time span. The server would calculate the time from that. 

How much can you trust your user base? How precise does the information need to be? To some degree can you allow for some invalid time info - realistically not many users are going to be tampering with their clock settings that much so there would only be a few possible edge cases. It's all relative to your requirements

Answer (score 1):

I beg to differ : how long ago is quite risky. For example some countries have a daylight saving time

I think you should look into ready to use solution like couchdb( and his sqlite cousin :pouchdb): you can make explicit or implicits  synchronisation, and there's quite a work done for solving conflicts 
http://guide.couchdb.org/draft/conflicts.html

Comment: Daylight savings and locale is not only for displaying time in a format that users understand, I am referring to unix time in my answer. 

As for syncing, if it was existing data then a version number can be used and it shouldn't be a problem to merge changes. However, when I read the question I taken it to mean that end users are sending new data to the webapp. This means it's not a case of resolving conflicts.

It really depends on what they want to achieve.

Comment: It's ybout resolving conflicts since you can add/edit data on the mobile and web app. Don't know if I want to use couchDB. ALso need to check if it is even supported by PhoneGap or any other software I might use for the mobile part.

Comment: for editing existing data, a version number on the object may be the way to go. If there are conflicts during the connection to the server, then you could have some logic to work out whichever is most recent or prompt the user to confirm which data is best to keep. 

I think it's perfectly acceptable to ask the user. It's what happens when my phone contacts sync to my computer (just the way I want it). 

I'm not sure how well NoSQL will help in this use case but it's certainly worth trying out. I've used CouchDB before, you could get a prototype solution up and running in no time.

Answer (score 1):

Try http://www.couchbase.com/communities/couchbase-lite. It's an embedded NoSQL store for iOS and Android, which is able to sync with CouchDB and Couchbase Server.